# Is there a conceptual limitation to have a clone stage function in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

In Bamboo, you can:

- clone a job
- clone a plan

Why is it not possible to clone a stage, I mean, could there be a certain reason to not have it?

Comment: Stages group jobs inside plans. Are these stages cloned as well when the plans containing them are cloned?

Comment: yes, they will be cloned. But to clone a stage inside a plan, you need currently to create a new stage and clone jobs into it.

Answer (score 2):

Stages group jobs inside plans. So technically they are cloned when the respective plans are cloned.

Which means that missing the ability to clone a specific stage should be just a UX/usability/functionality issue, not a conceptual one.

There *might* be a non-trivial implementation details when cloning stages - they may carry inside stage sequencing information, as in "pointers" to the stage objects preceeding and/or following them inside the plan "pipeline", which might be a bit more difficult to handle when cloning just one stage in the sequence. These would be easier to handle when cloning entire plans as the entire sequence of stages is cloned, there will always be a 1:1 relationship between the stages.